# How to add expected condition to function which finds element

Tags: c#, selenium

I have code which finds element with delay, but sometimes element is already but not clickable and not available in DOM, so what i should to add to my code to check those arguments

```
public IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver, By howBy, int timeoutInSeconds = 10)
        {
            TimeSpan elementTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            IWebElement elementfound = null;

            try
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, elementTimeOut);
                elementfound = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        elementfound = driver.FindElement(howBy);
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Please fail NoSuchElementException");
                        throw;
                    }

                    return elementfound;
                });
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Please fail WebDriverTimeoutException");
                throw;
            }

            return elementfound;
        }
```

Comment: Don't, waiting for an element to be clickable in a generic finder so you can click it is useless since the driver already performs those checks and some more that are not covered by `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`. Moreover, testing the state is expensive and there's no guaranty that the element will be clickable when the click is performed. The recommended approach is to perform the click in a custom waiter which will retry depending on the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, 
It'll check if it's 'visible' by using the standard `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`, 
it'll then simply check if the `element.isEnabled()` is `true` or not.

This can be condensed slightly, this basically means (simplified, in C#):

1. Wait until the element is returned from the DOM
2. Wait until the element's `.Displayed` property is true (which is essentially what `visibilityOfElementLocated` is checking for).
3. Wait until the element's `.Enabled` property is true (which is essentially what the `elementToBeClickable` is checking for).

I would implement this like so (adding onto the current set of `ExpectedConditions`, but there are multiple ways of doing it:

```
// <param name="locator">The locator used to find the element.</param>
// <returns>The <see cref="IWebElement"/> once it is located, visible and clickable.</returns>
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsClickable(By locator)
{
    return driver =>
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(locator);
        return (element != null && element.Displayed && element.Enabled) ? element : null;
    };
}
```

Above method can be used something like:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var clickableElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("id")));
```

However, you can pass `howBy` as the param of `ElementIsClickable()` method.

Answer (score 0):

**elementToBeClickable** is used to wait for an element to be clickable .

Please use the following code inside your method.

```
elementfound  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(howBy);
```